# Reversing string by word in java (not using StringBuilder)

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting a method to return anything. The code is supposed to take a string, reverse the string by word, and return the new string.

This is for a school assignment, and i'm trying to avoid using stringbuilder since it's not covered by the text.  I'm also trying to use syntax I understand as much as possible for obvious reasons.

```
public static String reverseByWord(String s){
    String forward[] = s.split("\\s+");
    String backward = new String();
    for (int i=forward.length-1; i< forward.length-1; i--){
        backward += forward[i];
    }

    return backward;
```

Input example: "The quick brown fox"
Output expected: "fox brown quick The"
Output: nothing

Comment: You start at `i=forward.length-1`. So `i< forward.length-1` is not true on the first iteration and loop body is never entered. You probably meant `i >= 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **for loop** condition is not correct.
Your logic should be from last String length to starting of string i.e 0.

```
for (int i=forward.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    backward += forward[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=forward.length-1; i< forward.length-1; i--){
    backward += forward[i];
}
```

This line, `int i = forward.length-1; i < forward.length-1`

You set i to `forward.length - 1`, then you immediately tell the for loop that it should executed only if i is less than `forward.length - 1`

A really simple solution, just set the condition to `i >= 0`

Comment: I've been staring at code too long if I missed that.
for (int i=forward.length-1; i >= 0; i--)

Thanks a lot!